# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject could not convert string to DateTime when using non-us date formats

Tags: c#, javascript, json, json.net

I have the following serialized json object:

```
"{\"LineItems\":[{\"LineID\":1,\"QuoteID\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"Quantity\":\"1\",\"UnitPriceExTax\":\"2\",\"UnitPriceTaxRate\":\"2\",\"UnitPriceTaxAmt\":0,\"LineTotalExTax\":2,\"LineTotalTaxAmt\":0.040000000000000036,\"LineTotalIncTax\":2.04}],\"QuoteID\":[],\"CurrencyID\":\"2\",\"SupplierRef\":\"SDFSFSDF\",\"DeliveryDate\":\"22/02/2014\",\"QuoteAvailablityStartDate\":\"13/02/2014\",\"QuoteAvailablityEndDate\":\"09/02/2014\",\"OpeningComments\":\"WWSFSFS \",\"PricingComments\":\"XSDFSDF \",\"DeliveryComments\":\"SDFSFSDF SDFSFSF\",\"TermsComments\":\"SFSFSDF SDFSFSDF SDFS\",\"FreightExTax\":\"1\",\"FreightExTax2\":1,\"FreightTaxRate\":\"1\",\"FreightTaxAmt\":0.010000000000000009,\"FreightIncTax\":1.01,\"TotalLinesExTax\":2,\"TotalLinesTaxAmt\":0.040000000000000036,\"TotalExTax\":3,\"TotalTaxAmt\":0.050000000000000044,\"TotalIncTax\":3.05}"
```

One this is sent to the server I am trying to deserialize as follows:

```
var json = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["EoiDraftModel"];
var ld = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EoiDraftViewModel>(json);
```

And Im hitting an error:

> "Could not convert string to DateTime: 13/02/2014. Path
>   'DeliveryDate', line 1, position 323."

Since the date is valid I'm assuming its a problem with non-us format. In fact I know it is because if I do less than 13 for my days it deserializes just fine. So how do I indicate to  deserializer to use non-us dates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing dates with dd/mm/yyyy format using Json.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21256132/10263)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try specifying the `DateTime` format specifically using an `IsoDateTimeConverter`, and pass it into the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()` method.

```
...
var json = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["EoiDraftModel"];

var format = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // your datetime format
var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = format };

var ld = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EoiDraftViewModel>(json, dateTimeConverter);
...
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful!

Comment: Really helpful solution.