# Deserializing dates with dd/MM/yyyy format within a List using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, date, datetime

I am using the solution in the follow SO post ([Deserializing dates with dd/mm/yyyy format using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net)), but am getting the following error when trying to Deserialize MyObject:

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = "{\"data\":[{\"courseID\":43547,\"endDate\":\"01/01/2014\"},{\"courseID\":40949,\"endDate\":\"10/04/2013\"},{\"courseID\":40439,\"endDate\":\"7/03/2013\"}]}";

        var myCheckedCourses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json, 
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" });

    }
}

class MyObject
{
    public List<Object2> data { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject]
public class Object2
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `7/03/2013` isn't in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Comment: Hi @AllanHorwitz I suggest you that date field in json should be in UTC Format. And it will good for you and server too.

Answer (score 1):

The date format needed to be changed to d/MM/yyyy.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not the right answer. Does that really work for you?