# SqlDateTime overflow when deserialize json object to model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have json object with date field as `dd/mm/yyyy`.
When I deserialized JObject to model I have date `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}` and this is my problem.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public int SaveTimesheetList(JObject taskJson)
    {
        dynamic model = taskJson;

        var newTask = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimesheetListModel>(model.ToString());

        return TimesheetService.SaveArbitraryTask(newTask, ProjectService.CurrentUserId);
    }
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime(v=vs.110).aspx): "Represents the date and time data ranging in value from January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999" - since your value isn't in that range, you need to spot that and adjust it. What value do you want to adjust it to?

Comment: Man, I know it, but problem that is my date in json object is random date of 2015 year without the time, and when it's deserializing I have `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`

Comment: So what does the JSON look like?

Comment: I copied from visual studio debug window: `((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)(taskJson)) {\r\n  "ProjectID": 4,\r\n  "Date": "11/09/2015",\r\n  "TaskDescription": "asdasdad",\r\n  "TimeWorked": "4",\r\n  "Note": null,\r\n  "isSaved": true\r\n}`

Comment: Have you tried [setting the date format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21256132/10263) used for deserialization?