# Cannot deserialize datetime property Neo4j using C# client in a transaction

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, neo4j, json.net

My problem is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423174/cannot-deserialize-datetime-property-neo4j-using-c-sharp-client#new-answer):

I'm having the same failure, but in a different scenario:

At run time the error is occurring inside;

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Doing stuff here fails only within a transaction!
    scope.Complete();
}
```

The same problem code runs perfectly fine when executed outside of a transaction!

The error message is:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233088   LineNumber=1   LinePosition=33   Message=Could
>   not convert string to DateTime: 15/05/2016 09:23:34 +00:00. Path 'a',
>   line 1, position 33.   Path=a   Source=Neo4jClient

The code versions are:

Neo4jClient version=1.1.0.16
Newtonsoft.Json version=8.0.1

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net) basically says I can pass a

```
new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" }
```

To the serialisation but as that is inside Neo4jClient how can I implement that.

Answer

```
client.JsonConverters.Add( new IsoDateTimeConverter() );
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up the converter using default settings before creating the client?  See [Registering a custom JsonConverter globally in Json.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19510532/10263)

Comment: Thanks Brian, your clue led me to find the answer. I did not test just setting it globally as I discovered the right property of the neo4jClient to use.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  You might consider posting an answer to your own question in case someone else runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line of code immediately after creating the client, solved the of datetime serialisation problem.

Note: my culture is en-GB so I am not sure if this would need finegling to adjust for your culture settings.

```
client.JsonConverters.Add( new IsoDateTimeConverter() );
```

I think there are numerous ways of making this happen but this one definately works.