# Deserializing json string containing date in UK format and time with AM/PM

Tags: c#, jquery, json, date, datetime

I have jquery `timepicker` which return value in 12:00 AM format.
 and a jquery `datepicker` which return date in uk date format.

data model class

```
pulic class dbModel{
   pulic DateTime DateOn{get;set;}
   pulic DateTime StartTime{get;set;}//time only
   pulic DateTime EndTime{get;set;}//time only
}
```

time picker:

```
 $('#eEndTime').timepicker(
       {
           template: false,
           showInputs: false,
           minuteStep: 5
       });
```

json string:

```
  strModel{"DateOn","16/12/2015","StartTime","12:35 PM","EndTime","12:40 PM"}
```

I am trying to convert this to datetime in c# as follow:

```
dbModel model=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dbModel>(strModel, new  IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat ="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" });
```

but its not working throws error date is not in correct format.

**Question**

how i can deserialize **`16/12/2015`**(uk format) and AM/PM time to Datetime in c#  using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm

Comment: Also: custom datetime format in Json.Net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net

Comment: Your `DateTimeFormat` is incorrect, it should be `DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"`

Comment: i have tried with hh:mm:ss too but its not working

Comment: Your date format (`16/12/2015 12:35 PM`) does not have a `seconds` component, so obviously `hh:mm:ss` format would not work...