# How to deserialize object with date in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have this Json from a web api:

```
jsonstring ={"users":[{"id":1123,"last_update":"2016-02-28 14:53:04"}],"page":1,"pages":1}
```

which I want to deserialize in an object like:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public User[] users { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime last_update { get; set; }
}
```

for this I use:

```
 var obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);
```

the result has `null` for `last_update`.

`jsonstring` is a string result from `WebClient.DownloadString(url)`; which look like above example.

How can I get the date on deserialization?

Edit:

None of the solutions from this post [Deserializing dates with dd/mm/yyyy format using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net) help me fix my issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString, 
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" });
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4mowXO)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net

Comment: not working, with Nullable datetime, I get null, and non Nullable datetime I get min datetime.

Comment: See a working demo

Comment: Hi Adrian, I saw your example, its working with static object, but when I use the method on the api result jsonstring, is not working. I will accept your answer, and now I need to figure out why on api result is not working.

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx Maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

Change the property `last_update`  as [Nullable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime), Then it allows you to assign the null literal to the DateTime type. It provides another level of indirection. So use like the following:

```
public DateTime? last_update { get; set; }
```

This is for accepting The date even if it is null, you can specify the Date format While Deserializing the JSON. Use this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net) for that

Comment: I tried that, the results still null for date

Answer (score -1):

`"2016-02-28 14:53:04"` is not a valid RFC3339 date time, and I think it can't parse it because of that.

It has to be:

```
2016-02-28T14:53:04
```

Also note that the can't be null, since `DateTime` is a struct. To make it nullable, make the data type `DateTime?` which does allow null values.