# Newtonsoft.JSON Deserialize the datetime string in c#?

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I have to deserialize a JSON string in C#. And in my serealize JSON string there is a datetime field. Below is the JSON string format -

{"Date" : "2016-09-20T18:29:00.0000000"}

But when I am desealizing the above string like below -

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(entity, new IsoDateTimeConverter {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff"                
        });
```

I am getting the below string-

```
{"Date" : "2016-09-20T18:29:00"}
```

Means I am not getting the milliseconds value while it's 000.

Can anyone help me out on this.

## Updating my question :

Actually I am deserializing my object/entity by Newtonsoft and which there is a datetime field which I want to format.

```
 return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(entity, new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff"                             
        });
```

But as a result I am not getting the datetime format that I mentioned. It's truncating the datetime string from milliseconds. Below is my datetime string -

```
2016-09-20T18:29:00.000
```

And I am getting string like below after deserialzation -

```
2016-09-20T18:29:00
```

Comment: There are no milliseconds in your example..

Comment: #stuartd, 0000000 is the milliseconds

Comment: There is no such thing as a "json datetime".

Comment: How did you get the string you presented?

Comment: I would refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21272518/3585278

Comment: your code is working, i just made a short test. stuartd is right about your example.

Comment: #avi, please read my updated question.