# newtonsoft json serialize timespan format

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Is it possible to specify custom format for `TimeSpan` serialization?
Using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

I would like to have serialized string in format HH:mm, so for example:

`TimeSpan.FromHours(5)` -> // "+05:00"

`TimeSpan.FromHours(-5)` -> // "-05:00"

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Here's a TimeSpan converter you can add to your project:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonTools
{
    /// <summary>
    /// TimeSpans are not serialized consistently depending on what properties are present. So this 
    /// serializer will ensure the format is maintained no matter what.
    /// </summary>
    public class TimespanConverter : JsonConverter<TimeSpan>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Format: Days.Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds
        /// </summary>
        public const string TimeSpanFormatString = @"d\.hh\:mm\:ss\:FFF";

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, TimeSpan value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var timespanFormatted = $"{value.ToString(TimeSpanFormatString)}";
            writer.WriteValue(timespanFormatted);
        }

        public override TimeSpan ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, TimeSpan existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            TimeSpan parsedTimeSpan;
            TimeSpan.TryParseExact((string)reader.Value, TimeSpanFormatString, null, out parsedTimeSpan);
            return parsedTimeSpan;
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
public class Schedule
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TimespanConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    public TimeSpan Delay { get; set; }
}
```

## **Notes:**

1. [Reference for TimeSpan serialization formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)
2. I found that when generating a schema using Newtonsoft I had to include the TypeNameHandling attribute or the TimeSpan type name was not being serialized properly in the generated schema. That isn't necessary for the purpose here, but I included it anyway.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see [in the source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/9.0.1/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextWriter.cs#L698), there is no way of changing the format using predefined setting (like for `DateTime`).

What you can do is write a new `JsonConverter` for `TimeSpan` and handle the formatting as you see fit. Just be sure to use it by including it in `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` or by modifying the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a DateTime instance, and then add and subtract time from it like:

```
System.DateTime timeNow = System.DateTime.Now;
DateTime futureDateTime = timeNow.Add(new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0));
DateTime prevDateTime = timeNow.Add(new TimeSpan(-5, 0, 0));
```

To specify the times that you need. Then to put them into your string format:

```
futureDateTime.ToString("hh:mm") // 12 hour clock
```

To deserialize the string value back into DateTime objects with a certain format, there's an example of specifying a DateTimeFormat and IsoDateTimeConverter in this post:
[Deserializing dates with dd/mm/yyyy format using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net)

Comment: This is incorrect. If you want to hack `DateTime` like this, you would have to use `<someDate>.Date`, eg. `DateTime.Now.Date` (aka `DateTime.Today`), so the time component is empty and added `TimeSpan` is presented correctly. What is more, this will only work for values less than 24h and only non-negative ones - how do you want to present negative time component in `DateTime`?