# Deserializing nested dates with dd/MM/yyyy using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, date, serialization

This seems to be much like a duplicate of [Deserializing dates with dd/mm/yyyy format using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net) but the proposed solution doesn't seem to work for me.

I have a test case

```
void Main()
{
    if (File.Exists("config.json"))
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("config.json");
        var dateTimeConverter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" };
        PositionForwardingConfiguration config = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PositionForwardingConfiguration>(json, dateTimeConverter);
        foreach (var client in config.ClientConfiguration.clients)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Date: {0}", client.MiniumDate));
        }
        json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config, dateTimeConverter);
        Debug.WriteLine(json);
    }

}
public class PositionForwardingConfiguration
{
    public ClientConfiguration ClientConfiguration { get; set; }
}

public class ClientConfiguration
{
    public ClientInfo[] clients { get; set; }
}
public class ClientInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime MiniumDate { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public Uri Endpoint { get; set; }
}
```

that produces output like

```
Date: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Date: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Date: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
{"ClientConfiguration":{"clients":[{"Id":1,"Name":"1","MiniumDate":"01/01/0001","Token":"Token 1","Endpoint":"http://1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"2","MiniumDate":"01/01/0001","Token":"Token 2","Endpoint":"http://2"},{"Id":3,"Name":"3","MiniumDate":"01/01/0001","Token":"Token 3","Endpoint":"http://3"}]}}
```

Particular note the date is not deserializing or serializing using the supplied converter. Has something changed with Newtonsoft.JSON to make this not work? My input looks like

```
{
    "ClientConfiguration": {
        "clients": [
        {
            "Id" : 1,
            "Name" : "1",
            "MinimumDate" : "01/01/2017",
            "Token" : "Token 1",
            "Endpoint" : "http://1"
        },
        {
            "Id" : 2,
            "Name" : "2",
            "MinimumDate" : "02/01/2017",
            "Token" : "Token 2",
            "Endpoint" : "http://2"
        },
        {
            "Id" : 3,
            "Name" : "3",
            "MinimumDate" : "03/01/2017",
            "Token" : "Token 3",
            "Endpoint" : "http://3"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: I don't see where you are using the date/time converter for deserialization?

Comment: The problem is that the date time converter
        var dateTimeConverter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" };
        PositionForwardingConfiguration config = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PositionForwardingConfiguration>(json);
 doesn't seem to be used in the nested classes. I am not sure how to make the deserialization process use the converter I am passing to the base.

Comment: You aren't passing it to the base converter though, it should be something like `config = ... DeserializeObject<PositionForwar‌​dingConfiguration>(j‌​son, dateTimeConverter)` You only use the `dateTimeConverter` when you serialize at the end...

Comment: By the way, your data structure has a member named `MiniumDate` while the input file uses `MinimumDate`, the misspelled member is not getting populated with the data from your input file for obvious reasons.