# DateTime-System.FormatException after deserialize json-String to DataSet

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, datetime, json.net

i have a big problem with a DateTime-Format after deserializing a json-string to a Dataset.

```
Dim formatter = new JsonSerializerSettings() With { .DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ" }
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,formatter)
```

After this two lines I get a well formed DateTime-Format
(e.g. "2015-11-24T09:36:00Z")

But after that, I have to convert this json-string to a DataSet-Object.
I do it like this:

```
Dim ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(json,formatter)
```

And now, the DateTime-Value looks like this: "11/24/2015 09:36:00"

Finally this value ends in an Exception, that it is not a valide DateTime, if I want do parse it to an DateTime...

```
DateTime.Parse("11/24/2015 09:36:00")
```

So maybe there are some formatters which i have to use?
I don't know...

Hope you can help me!
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
Sample-Jsonstring:

```
{"records":[{"Key":"EIG*11111","ChangeDate":"2015-11-24T09:36:00Z"}]}
```

This ChangeDate will be formatted to #11/24/2015 09:36:00 AM# in the DataRow

Comment: Try `DateTime.ParseExact` with a format string instead.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` is culture-specific and relies on localization. Check if your computer format is MM/DD/YYY and not  DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share sample JSON that reproduces the problem -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.NET has `IsoDateTimeConverter` class where you can specify date format to parse formatted UTC datetime in JSON string as `DateTime` with [`DateTimeFormat`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter_DateTimeFormat.htm) property. The property usage should be like this:

```
Dim formatter As New IsoDateTimeConverter With { .DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" }
Dim ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(json, formatter)
```

Or use it in one-line form:

```
Dim ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(json, New IsoDateTimeConverter With { .DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" })
```

Note that you need adding `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters` namespace to enable `IsoDateTimeConverter` class.

Afterwards, use `DateTime.ParseExact()` with specified format above to make sure that returned date string can be converted to `DateTime` type.

Similar issue (in C# context):

[Deserializing dates with dd/mm/yyyy format using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net)

Comment: Wow! Thank you, it runs like a charm. Well explained!