# value changes when data is sent over Https

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

In ASP.NET WebApi:
I have a DTO class:

```
public class DTO
{
    public string Date {get; set;}
}
```

when the client (an Internet Explorer plugin) requests data from this WebApi, I return `IEnumerable<DTO>` like this:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, dtoObject)
```

Where `dtoObject` is of type `IEnumerable<DTO>`.
While debugging, I check the value of `dtoObject[0].Date` and it shows `22-Nov-18 12:00:00 AM`, and this is the expected value.

In the Internet Explorer plugin:
I have a model class called `Model`:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Date {get; set;}
}
```

I request the WebApi Like this:

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, requestDto);
var returnJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Model>>(returnJson)
```

Now, when I check `result[0].Date` I get, `12/11/2018 12:00:00 AM`
while I am expecting `22-Nov-18 12:00:00 AM`

I have read that date values are serialized differently by different libraries/languages.. But, I am using a `string` to store the value then why is the value getting changed? I want to receive the `Date` value in `dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt` format. How do I achieve that?

Comment: you really should include enough code, so that we readers, can reproduce the result. 
This problem could be a number of things. Culture override, format override. etc.
You really just need to entity.DateTimeProperty.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy").
Could also be that the other hoster simply configured the data to be in this format, and you must now parse that data on your side.

Comment: A string containing a date won't change its format when transferred through JSON. It's your display logic that does this.

Comment: I don't have a display logic. I debug my plugin and see `entity.date` and I get `"07/11/2018 12:00:00 AM"`

Comment: Is it worth using a deserialisation date formatter?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net See @Foy 's answer.  Same as Rebecca's answer below in this question, but it's local, not global.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share the value of the string `returnJson`?

Comment: It looks like this issue explains why you got a different string: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stated problem is unable to be reproduced in the following tests.

A unit test that serializes a `DTO` and then deserializes a `Model` behaves as expected

```
[Test]
public void __String_Dates_Should_Match() {
    //Arrange
    var date = "22-Nov-18 12:00:00 AM";
    var dtoObject = new[] { new DTO { Date = date } };
    var returnJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtoObject);

    //Act
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Model>>(returnJson);

    //Assert
    result.First()
        .Should().NotBeNull()
        .And.Match<Model>(_ => _.Date == date);
}
```

An integration test using in-memory Web API also behaves as expected

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [Test]
    public async Task __WebApi_Dates_Should_Match() {
        //Arrange
        var date = "22-Nov-18 12:00:00 AM";
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        var httpServer = new HttpServer(config);
        var client = new HttpClient(httpServer);

        //Act
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/test/data");
        var returnJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //Assert
        response.IsSuccessStatusCode.Should().BeTrue();

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Model>>(returnJson);
        result.First()
            .Should().NotBeNull()
            .And.Match<Model>(_ => _.Date == date);
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestApiController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("data")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
        var date = "22-Nov-18 12:00:00 AM";
        var dtoObject = new[] { new DTO { Date = date } };
        return Ok(dtoObject);
    }
}
```

Given that the assigned properties are strings, they should not be affected by date conversion.

The issue then would be how you are assigning the `DateTime` to the properties. Which could be as a result of the current culture the code is running under.

```
var value = new DTO { 
    Date = someDateTime.ToString()
};
```

which is where the desired date format should be applied

```
var value = new DTO { 
    Date = someDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ISO-8601 DateTime formater in WebAPI config for a consistent date format:

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters[0] = new JsonNetFormatter(serializerSettings);
```

Dates will then be returned as:

```
{
   "Date": "2018-11-20T12:16:00"
}
```

In your client you need to expect the same format when deserializing the JSON to your internal object.

Comment: I can't find `JsonNetFormatter`. Do I need to add any reference for this class? BTW, Is it possible for the value to change while serializing/deserializing even when it is stored in a variable of type `string` ?

Comment: I can't change the global settings. Is there any way to do it locally.