# JSON Deserialization issue with DateTime in MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, json, datetime, datetime-format

I am having a JSON with a date time in MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss format, for example, 12/20/2000 10:30:00.

The complete JSON will be something similar to this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 10001,
        "name": "Name 1",
        "date": "10/01/2022 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 10002,
        "name": "Name 2",
        "date": "10/01/2022 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 10003,
        "name": "Name 3",
        "date": "10/01/2022 00:00:00"
    }
]
```

I have a c# class with id, name and date where the date is a DateTime type.
I am trying to convert the JSON object to a list of Objects, but I am getting a conversion error as shown below.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to deserialize response content to the type of List`1)\r\n ---> System.Exception: Unable to deserialize response content to the type of List`1\r\n
```

If I remove the date from the class, everything works fine.

If I convert the date to a string type, it works. But I need to keep it as DateTime.

Comment: where did you get that JSON from? if you have any control over the creating system, you should change it to produce ISO-datetime-strings instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing dates with dd/MM/yyyy format using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256132/deserializing-dates-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format-using-json-net)

Comment: I don't have control as the JSON I am getting from an external API. Above one is just a sample. @FranzGleichmann

Comment: [What is the "right" JSON date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format), so you are out of luck, and should contact the creator of this external API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" };
    
List<Data> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(json, jsonSettings);

public class Data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this, with DateTime properties you need to provide the JsonConverter.

```
public class Root
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

var ls = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(content, new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" });
```

**DeserializeObject Declaration:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Deserializes the JSON to the specified .NET type using a collection of <see cref="JsonConverter"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object to deserialize to.</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">The JSON to deserialize.</param>
/// <param name="converters">Converters to use while deserializing.</param>
/// <returns>The deserialized object from the JSON string.</returns>
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static T? DeserializeObject<T>(string value, params JsonConverter[] converters)
{
    return (T?)DeserializeObject(value, typeof(T), converters);
}
```

**Reference**: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter_DateTimeFormat.htm